# Which url name should be used for api performing the membership withdrawal function

Tags: api-design, naming, restful-url, http-method

Q1. Is it okay to use the word "deregistration" in the API specification,
or should I use "signout"?
Which one is better?

Q2. And I wonder if the actual logic of membership withdrawal API is just changing user's status to "pending", can I specify the API's HTTP Method to DELETE, or should I use PATCH?

Which HTTP method of 'user withdrawl api' is more RESTful?

I tried "signout" to our service's user withdrawal API's name, but it can misleading developer to understand it to 'logout' so I want to know the common naming convention.

Comment: If by "performing the membership withdrawal function" you mean permanently deleting a user's account (or canceling their subscription?), then definitely don't use "signout" because that usually means the same thing as "logout" and implies no permanent change will be made to the user account's status.

Comment: It looks like your question has more than one part. It might be better to split it up and ask two separate questions, or otherwise to edit this one to show how the two issues relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas. There's no absolute right and wrong - maybe more important is keeping consistency with your existing REST structure

- If you're removing the user entirely, so they no longer exist at all:
  `DELETE /api/users/{id}`
- If you're keeping the user in the system, but removing them from the list of active users, consider the philosophy of deleting them from a sub collection: `DELETE /api/users/active/{id}`
- You've already mentioned patch. Personally I don't like that, because it puts the onus on the client to *know* which fields it needs to patch. That's ok while it's just a single "status" field... But if you ever need to introduce more complex state with extra fields (say a "deactivated date") then either the client would break, or the PATCH would need mangling by the server (which isn't really in the spirit of it). By using a simple DELETE verb, like the two above options, you're protected from that.